# Detecting Negative Cycles in Undirected Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I recently faced the problem of quickly detecting negative cycles in undirected, weighted graphs. Resorting to the Bellman-Ford Algorithm, as commonly suggested, turned out to be very inefficient and also needed some care to prevent the algorithm from ping ponging between a pair of vertices adjacent to a negative edge.
Another thing about using the Bellman-Ford algorithm for detecting negative cycles is that it requires $O(n^3)$ preprocessing before it allows the detection of negative cycles, not to mention that experiments suggest, that it gets "stuck" in a single such cycle.

Now my idea would be to

> - calculate the graph's MST
> - calculate the all pairs shortest path distances of the MST
> - report the existence of a negative cycle, if an edge can be found, for which $(u,v)\in E\setminus\{ E\cap MST\}$ and $dist_{MST}(u,v)+w(v,u) \lt 0$ holds.

the complexity would be $O(n^2)$ instead of $O(n^3)$, but:

**Questions**

- would the algorithm sketched above correctly report the existence of negative cycles, resp. in which cases will it fail?
- is the set of edges that are not in the MST, but whose union with the edges on the shortest MST-path between their adjacent vertices is a negative cycle, represent a negative-cycle transversal of the graph?

**Addendum**
In the abstract of this [article](http://www.cse.psu.edu/%7Ekxm85/papers/NegCycle-FAW09.pdf) it is stated, that the problem of detecting negative cost cycles in undirected graphs (UNCCD problem) is "*significantly harder than the corresponding problem in directed graphs*" and the complexities of different algorithms are given, ranging from $O(n^{2.75}\log n)$ to $O(n^6)$

Comment: What if the negative cycles are on the set of edges not in the tree? I don't think it would be difficult to come with an example where all the negative cycles are on the complement of the tree.

Comment: I also had that idea, but I doubt that it will be easy to find a counterexample, simply because every edge on the shortest MST-path between the vertices to an edge outside the MST can't be longer than that edge.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is negative in the general case!

Counterexamples can be easily constructed in the following way:

- take a graph, that resembles a tree with at least one sufficiently long shortest path.
- assign to each tree-edge weight $1$, and $-k\ < -2$ to two edges $e$ and $f$, which are at least $2k-2$ edges of weight $1$ apart.
- insert two edges, that are not tree edges and resemble a perfect matching on the vertices adjacent to the two negative edges and assign weight $2$ to both edges.

With the above construction, we have created a negative cycle of length $-2k-2+4\ < -2$ that contains two non-tree edges.
The shortest cycle containing only a single non-tree edge and both negative edges is however $\ > (-2k)\ +\ (2k-2)\ +\ (2) \ge\ 0$.

This demonstrates that negative cycles may go undetected with the $MST$-heuristic; it may however still be useful as a fast sufficient check for negative cycles.